# TSQL using system functions within dynamic statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

Is it possible to use SQL Server system functions like `@@ROWCOUNT` within dynamic statement ?

I was trying to do this but failed :

```
USE NORTHWIND

SELECT * FROM Customers
EXEC ('SELECT ''RowCount is equal to ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @@ROWCOUNT))
```

It gives me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do but you can't do it directly in the `EXEC` call. [The grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) is below.

```
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
    [ AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name ' ]
[;]
```

so it doesn't allow anything other than string literals / variables (and parameters) and the `+` operator.

So you would need to concatenate it into the string *first* then `EXEC(@YourString)`

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT *
FROM   Customers;

SET @Sql = 'SELECT ''RowCount is equal to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ROWCOUNT) + '''';

EXEC (@Sql);
```

But you don't need dynamic SQL here anyway.

```
SELECT 'RowCount is equal to ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @@ROWCOUNT)
```

works fine.

Take care that there are no intervening statements at all between the statement with the `SELECT` and that retrieving the rowcount or it will be reset.